# How do I call back a variable that is a float in an input statement?

Tags: python

I'm creating a calculator and am trying to callback the previous result as one of the numbers in a new problem. So I have a variable named "RESULT" that's assigned to the value of the previous equation, but how do I call it back in an input?

My program asks for two numbers and I try to put in one of them as "RESULT" but get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/local/submission/sci_calculator.py", line 63, in <module>
    num2 = float(input("Enter second operand: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RESULT'
```

Comment: Show us the full code and the full error message.  Otherwise we are just guessing what you actually did.

Comment: But at a guess, you used `float("RESULT")` instead of `float(RESULT)`...

Comment: @JohnGordon, given the traceback more likely they enter `RESULT` when asked for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic way to refer to an internal variable with `input()`.

But you can write some simple code to check for that case before calling `float()`:

```
num2 = input("Enter second operand: ")

# if they typed RESULT, use that variable
if num2 == "RESULT":
    num2 = RESULT

# otherwise convert the answer to a float
else:
    num2 = float(num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much wrote this:

```
    RESULT = 42
    prompt = "Enter second operand: "
    num2 = float(input(prompt))
```

Use an `or` disjunction to supply a convenience default:

```
    num2 = float(input(prompt) or RESULT)
```

When the user hits just ENTER, the `input()` returns `""` empty-string,
which is falsey, so the disjunction evaluates to its second argument.
When the user types e.g. `86` ENTER, the two-character string `"86"`
is truthy so the disjunction short circuits and returns it.

For more complex defaulting behavior,
you should probably `def` a helper function.

Comment: _When the user hits just ENTER_ But that's clearly not what they did...

Comment: Indeed. I was trying to solve the business problem, in the simplest way that a naive engineer could address it.